# Is it possible to convert an entire PDF file to a bunch images using ImageMagick (Ubuntu, Python)?

Tags: python, bash, imagemagick

I have a Python app which among others converts an entire PDF file to a few jpg. 
In Pycharm it is implemented by the code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["magick",Platforma_IoT.pdf,Platforma_IoT.jpg], shell=True)
```

That code in Pycharm on Windows 10 works completely fine, it converts every page of a pfd to jpg. But now I want to run that code using Bash console. Unfortunately, I am getting an error in the Bash:

```
import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/358.
./sd.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `["magick","Platforma_IoT.pdf","Platforma_IoT.jpg"],'
./sd.py: line 3: `subprocess.check_call(["magick","Platforma_IoT.pdf","Platforma_IoT.jpg"], shell = True)'
```

I also tried that code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["convert","Platforma_IoT.pdf","Platforma_IoT.jpg"])
```

But I am getting the same error in the bash.

I just want to run code which converts every page of PDF to an image using bash console. How can I do that?

Comment: In bash window, simply type: `convert Platforma_IoT.pdf Platforma_IoT.jpg`. That is assuming you have ImageMagick compiled and the path to ImageMagick is in your $PATH environment variable. Otherwise, put the full path to ImageMagick as part of the command for convert

Comment: @fmw42 I added ImageMagick to the enviroment variables but it doesn't help me. "magick : not found". How can I directly pass a ImageMagick path in the bash command? Now I just type "python3 name.py

Comment: However, I have a problem with adding environment variable. I have added in ".bashrc"  file: `ImageMagick='/mnt/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.9-Q16  export ImageMagick 'export PATH=$PATH:ImageMagick/bin' but $ImageMagick output looks like: -bash /mnt/c/Program: No such file or directory. I have tried ImageMagick=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/ImageMagick7.0.9-Q16 but it doesnt work

Comment: Ok, I used that link: https://www.tecmint.com/install-imagemagick-on-debian-ubuntu/ and it finaly works.

Answer (score 0):

You met a wrong script interpretation. Use shebang to define the right interpretator:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Or you can launch your script in python directly:

```
python3 script.py
```

Comment: You were right but still it doesn't work. `import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["magick","Platforma_IoT.pdf","Platforma_IoT.jpg"], shell=True)` works perfectly in the PyCharm but when I run it in the Bash console it throws an error: `Platforma_IoT.pdf: 1: Platforma_IoT.pdf: magick: not found
Traceback [..]  Command '['magick', 'Platforma_IoT.pdf', 'Platforma_IoT.jpg']' returned non-zero exit status 127`

Comment: @MuscleUpUp Probably, you have a different environment, and you didn't resolve all dependencies. IDE could resolve it for itself, but not for a whole system. Use `sudo apt install magic` at Ubuntu.